# Space considering as new line in html

Tags: html, css

We have two html files, by looks both look similar, but when we actually render, in one of them we have additional line breaks. May I know how to avoid it.

```html
<p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Calibri;font-family:Calibri;font-family:Calibri;"><feff><feff></span><span style="font-size: 12px; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; font-family: Calibri;"><feff></span><span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Calibri; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><feff></span><span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Calibri; color: rgb(27, 30, 36); background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><feff></span><span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Calibri; color: rgb(27, 30, 36); background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><feff></span><span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Calibri; color: rgb(27, 30, 36); background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><feff></span><span style="font-size: 9pt; color: rgb(27, 30, 36); background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"><feff></span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">Hi Mr. Calipjo,</span></span><span style="font-family:"Cambria",serif;
mso-ascii-theme-font:major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family:"Cambria",serif;mso-ascii-theme-font:
major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family:"Cambria",serif;mso-ascii-theme-font:
major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">Greetings!</span><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family:"Cambria",serif;mso-ascii-theme-font:
major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">We apologize for the inconvenient
that this may have cause you.</span><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family:"Cambria",serif;mso-ascii-theme-font:
major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">As of now we are still
coordinating this request to our support team, we are waiting for the feedback
from our support team.</span><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family:"Cambria",serif;mso-ascii-theme-font:
major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">We will update you once we received
a feedback.</span><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">









<p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Calibri;font-family:Calibri;font-family:Calibri;"><feff><feff></span><span style="font-size: 12px; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; font-family: Calibri;"><feff></span><span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Calibri; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><feff></span><span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Calibri; color: rgb(27, 30, 36); background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><feff></span><span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Calibri; color: rgb(27, 30, 36); background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><feff></span><span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Calibri; color: rgb(27, 30, 36); background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><feff></span><span style="font-size: 9pt; color: rgb(27, 30, 36); background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"><feff></span><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">Hi Mr. Calipjo,</span></span><span style="font-family:"Cambria",serif;
mso-ascii-theme-font:major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family:"Cambria",serif;mso-ascii-theme-font:
major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family:"Cambria",serif;mso-ascii-theme-font:
major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">Greetings!</span><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family:"Cambria",serif;mso-ascii-theme-font:
major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">We apologize for the inconvenient
that this may have cause you.</span><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family:"Cambria",serif;mso-ascii-theme-font:
major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">As of now we are still
coordinating this request to our support team, we are waiting for the feedback
from our support team.</span><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family:"Cambria",serif;mso-ascii-theme-font:
major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">We will update you once we received
a feedback.</span><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;"> </span></p><p><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">
```

Comment: Please share html code

Comment: **Very** bad practice to style inline - especially on this scale. Use an external stylesheet.

Comment: I have just edited and shared the code

Comment: you need to separate html and css

Comment: First part of the code is where we have issue, as you can see the second part is displayed without any additional line breaks.

Comment: @ShireeshaParampalli actually this html will be sent over email. This is how it generates in the code.

Comment: TL:DR from the duplicate, you can reset the font-size or line-height to make the anonymous block have 0 height (font-size:0 on body should do it)

Comment: Can you please share the duplicate question link ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif duplicate which you marked doesn't answer my question, if you notice my html, first part of html is fine, but not the second part. Though both are same .

Comment: you need to reset font-size ... in the first html code you are having extra tag where inside you have empty space and you are setting font-size to them. So no both code aren't the same

Answer (score 0):

In the first set of HTML I can see blank **p** tags with **&nbsp;**

```
<p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;">&nbsp;</span></p>
```

Whereas in the second set of HTML the **&nbsp;** is not rendered.

Removing **&nbsp;** from first HTML results in same output.

Hope this helps to debug further.

Comment: Yes, I figured out that. But  can we handle it by any encoding or any css change ?

Comment: This CSS solution is only based on your current html structure. `p.MsoNoSpacing:nth-child(3), p.MsoNoSpacing:nth-child(2), p.MsoNoSpacing:nth-child(5), p.MsoNoSpacing:nth-child(7), p.MsoNoSpacing:nth-child(8), p.MsoNoSpacing:nth-child(10) {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: Also bear in mind the nth-child CSS property doesnt support in most of the email clients. [CSS nth-child in email clients](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/)